# Auto Build Web Forms w/ Visual Studio 2010+ Pro?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Perhaps a stupid question... but if I have a well designed DBML with a handful of tables, is there a wizard or add-on for VS 2010 or better that would let a programmer drag the class (MS SQL table) onto a new blank web form (.aspx page/file) and have it auto-generate all or some of the following:

-very basic html table with 2 columns
-column 1 is labels of the db table fields
-column 2 is a server control for data input
-a submit button
-a very primitive event for saying all the controls back to the table

Obviously a person would have to edit what it generated a bit and style it up, but I feel like it would save a ton of time to just boot strap the form creation.

If there isn't what kind of process do you use?
Ive found that sometimes if I have a big table, I'll copy all the field names into excel and then use string concats to auto generate a lot of the html and 'save' event.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you're looking for [ASP.Net MVC Scaffolding](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/aspnet-scaffolding-overview).

Comment: Thanks HighCore... yes Scaffolding is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

As HighCore stated in the comments above, what I was looking for was the ability to scaffold my data model to help speed up development.

I looked around just a tiny bit and was unable to find something that suited my needs for VS2010 Pro, so I ended up creating a very simple (stupid) app that takes a DBML as an input, parses all the table information out of it, gives a drop down list of the tables and offers a "scaffold this" button.  On click it does a really basic string builder that creates a basic html scaffold, required field validators and two basic events (one for add record, one for load record).

maybe someday I'll convert my cheesy little app into a more robust VS plug-in. ;)

-Ted